# xhtml to html by using xsl java

Tags: java, html, xslt

I have template.xsl and template_index.xsl  templates which is used for dynamically create html from xhtml files. Locally from any folder i can open that xhtml file and view content which was created by xsl. So now i need to run this from server, and view content by addressing to the link of server. But it is empty when i want to view content from server. What i did wrong?

template.xsl:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ui="ui" xmlns:e="entity" xmlns:page="page" xmlns="html" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="exslt page e ui html">

        <!-- <Includes> -->

        <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

        <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

        <!-- <Data> -->

        <page:page name="about" title="API"></page:page>
        <!--xsl:param name="page" select="document('')/*/page:page"/-->

        <xsl:param name="pageXml">
          <page:page name="about" title="docs"/>
        </xsl:param>

        <xsl:variable name="title" select="(/ui:page/title | exslt:node-set($pageXml)/page:title)[1]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="page" select="(/ui:page/page:page | exslt:node-set($pageXml)/page:page)[1]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="subnav" select="(/ui:page/page:subnav | exslt:node-set($pageXml)/page:subnav)[1]"/>

        <xsl:variable name="page_name" select="/ui:page/@name"/>


        <!-- <Root> -->

        <xsl:template match="/ui:page">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</xsl:text>
            <html style="background-color:#414247;">
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8"/>
                <title><xsl:value-of select="$title"/></title>

                <link href="/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"  />
                <link href="/favicon.png" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
                <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300italic,600,700&amp;subset=latin,cyrillic-ext,cyrillic,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

                <link href="/_css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

                <xsl:for-each select="$page/page:stylesheet">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="{@href}" />
                </xsl:for-each>

                <xsl:apply-templates select="link" mode="html"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="style" mode="html"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="script" mode="html"/>

            </head>
            <body style="background-color:#414247;">
                <xsl:call-template name="header"/>

                <div class="body">
                    <xsl:call-template name="pagetree"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="ui:content"/>
                    <sub>dev</sub>
                </div>

                <xsl:call-template name="footer"/>
                <a id="feedback" href="http://idea.example.com/forum/"></a>
            </body>
        </html>
        </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="header">
    <div class="header"></div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="pagetree">
        <pagetree>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$subnav/descendant-or-self::page:item[@code=$page_name]/ancestor-or-self::page:item"/>
        </pagetree>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="page:item">
        <xsl:element name="a">
            <xsl:if test="@code=$page_name"><xsl:attribute name="class">selected</xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="@href"><xsl:value-of select="@href"/></xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="concat($page/@name,'_',@code,'.xml')"/></xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()"> / </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="footer">      
        <div class="footer">
            <img src="/_img/powered_by.png"/><br/><br/>
            &#169; 2015 Copyright. 
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ui:content">
       <xsl:apply-templates mode="html"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--xsl:template match="node() | @*" mode="html">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template-->

    <!-- template to copy elements -->
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="html">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="html"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="br" mode="html">
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::node()
                            [not(self::text() and normalize-space(.) = '')][1]
                            [self::br])">
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
          </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to copy attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="@*" mode="html">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to copy the rest of the nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="comment() | text() | processing-instruction()" mode="html">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="style" mode="html">
       <xsl:element name="style">
            <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
       </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

template_index.xsl:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ui="ui" xmlns:e="entity" xmlns:page="page" xmlns="html" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="exslt page e ui html">

        <!-- <Includes> -->

        <xsl:import href="template.xsl"/>

        <xsl:param name="pageXml">
            <page:title> API - text</page:title>
            <page:subnav>
                <page:item href="/docs/v1/" code="index" title="docs">
                    <page:item href="/api/v1/" code="track" title="trackI">
                        <page:item href="/api/v1/subscribe" code="subscribe" title="Push Service"></page:item>
                    </page:item>
                </page:item>
            </page:subnav>
        </xsl:param>

        <!-- <Root> -->

        <xsl:template name="sample">

        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

And index.xhtml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/_templates/template_index.xsl"?>
    <ui:page xmlns:ui="ui" name="index">
        <ui:content>
            <h1>H1</h1>

            Some text. <br/>
            Continue of text:

            <ul>
                <li><a href="/api/v1/">V1</a></li>
            </ul>

            <h2>H2</h2>
            texttext
            <div>
                <info>
                    <h3>H3</h3>
                    <tt>ttt</tt>
                </info>

                <info>
                    <h3>Example</h3>
                    <tt>tt</tt>
                </info>


            </div>


          </ui:content>
    </ui:page>
```

And what i did to server side, created webapp, copied xsl and css files to web-inf folder in webapp, copied index.xhtml to webapp folder, created servlet and wrote this:

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,
        ServletException {

     response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
     InputStream xslStream = this.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("template_index.xsl");
     TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
     Source xslSource = new StreamSource(xslStream);
     try {
     Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslSource);
     InputStream xmlStream = this.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("index.xhtml");
     Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(xmlStream);
     Result output = new StreamResult(response.getOutputStream());
     transformer.transform(xmlSource, output);
     } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Changed web.xml :

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<display-name>root</display-name>
<description>root</description>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>package.Servlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RootServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And from all this action when i try to localhost:8080/exampleapp/ , it is empty.

Comment: Your servlet-name elements do not match.  One contains `Servlet` while the other contains `RootServlet`.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the XML in the browser, it works. This is because, the browser transforms the XML content into HTML.

When you do the same stuff in Java, you need to remove the XSLT definition in XML file. As you already include both XSL and XML and the transformation is started in Java.

Comment: I think , u dont understand task. I need to view site content when i go to xhtml from deployed app like localhost:8080/exampleapp. When i go locally file://example/index.xhtml it is ok, i can view all of content , but when i go to the deployed app - it is empty

Comment: @bakash_erni, did you get any error in the server? When do you call the doPost method in servlet? If you are transforming the xhtml in java, why do you mention it in the welcome-file-list?